# Lucene shows strange unsubmitted documents

Tags: java, lucene

I submit a bunch of documents to a newly created index and commit/optimize & close the writer.
When I open and read from the index while in the same VM everything works as expected.
As soon as I close the VM, restart and read the index in a new application instance, I get a multitude of documents.

When I inspect the index via luke I see that the first documents in the index are as committed, but followed by very many documents containing only one field called "word".

Searching the index works as expected, but I got curious about the huge number returned by numDocs. By the way: I am using the lastest Java Lucene 3.0.2.

Any ideas on this anyone?

Best regards,

Alex

Here some code example:

```
File indexDirectory = new File(...);
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexDirectory);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);

// I also use a spellchecker, but this should not affect anything (I hope)
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(directory, true);
SpellChecker spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);
spellChecker.indexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(reader, "headline"));
spellChecker.indexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(reader, "intro"));


int numDocs = searcher.getIndexReader().numDocs();
int maxDoc = searcher.getIndexReader().maxDoc();
```

Comment: Please post a snippet with your indexing code. This may be a bug in your use of the code or a bug in Lucene, but more information is needed to decide which.

Comment: Hi Yuval, sorry I just saw your comment today ... I just edited and added my code example.

Answer (score 0):

I would try forcing the code to index one document, commit & close the writer, then inspect the index with Luke. This may give you a hint as to where the "word" documents are coming from.